# Assign more than one tag to ListView items

Tags: vb.net

I'm adding items to a ListView and assigning tags to them like this:

```
ListView1.Items.Add("FirstItem").Tag = "yellow"
```

Then, when I click on a button, I have all the items with the "yellow" tag disappear from the list:

```
    For Each listItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If listItem.Tag = "yellow" Then
            listItem.Remove()
        End If
    Next
```

My problem is that I want to assign multiple tags to a single item, so that when I click the button, items with two or more tags will be removed instead. How could I do this?

Comment: The fact that that code compiles shows that you must have `Option Strict Off`. I cannot recommend strongly enough that you turn it `On` in the properties of the current project and also in the IDE options, so that it will be `On` by default for future projects. It will flag various errors where you are not using appropriate data types, e.g `If listItem.Tag = "yellow" Then`. It will help you write better code that is less error-prone and more efficient.

Comment: Most likely, you should not be using a `ListView` in the first place. Many people use a `ListView` as though it is a grid control, which is not. If you are using only `Details` view with no grouping then you should almost certainly be using a `DataGridView` instead. With a `DataTable` bound to a `BindingSource` bound to a `DataGridView`, you could simply set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` to have rows hidden without being removed. Clearing the `Filter` would automatically redisplay those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not "assigning tags". There's no such thing as a tag. What you're doing is assigning `Strings` to the `Tag` properties. That `Tag` property is type `Object` specifically so that you can assign whatever object you want to it, so you need to assign an object that can contain the information you want. There are multiple ways to do that. You could use a delimited `String`, e.g.

```vb
ListView1.Items.Add("FirstItem").Tag = "yellow|blue|red"
```

and:

```vb
If CStr(listItem.Tag).Contains("yellow") Then
```

You could also use a `String` array or collection, e.g.

```vb
ListView1.Items.Add("FirstItem").Tag = {"yellow", "blue", "red"}
```

and:

```vb
If DirectCast(listItem.Tag, String()).Contains("yellow") Then
```

One advantage of the second option is that it makes using partially equal values easier. For instance, if you did this:

```vb
ListView1.Items.Add("FirstItem").Tag = "yellow|dark blue|red"
```

and:

```vb
If CStr(listItem.Tag).Contains("blue") Then
```

then your item would match when it logically shouldn't. If you do this:

```vb
ListView1.Items.Add("FirstItem").Tag = {"yellow", "dark blue", "red"}
```

and:

```vb
If DirectCast(listItem.Tag, String()).Contains("blue") Then
```

then your object will not match.